# why not working document.body.style.backgroundColor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm working on a logic that turns the screen black when I press the print screen shot key.
I'm changed background color but not working.
The console detected a change in value.

What's wrong?

I use typescript and next.js

```html
function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(false);

  useEffect(()=> {
    const keyUpListener = (e:KeyboardEvent) => {
      if (e.key === 'PrintScreen' || e.key === 'F13') {
        alert('test');
        document.body.style.zIndex = '999999';
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
        setValue(v => !v);
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener('keyup', keyUpListener);

    return () => document.removeEventListener('keyup', keyUpListener);
  }, []);

  return <>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </>;
}
```

Comment: You are mutating the DOM directly (*React anti-pattern*), and since no state/props updated no rerender is triggered.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not used to it.
Then, how should I fix this?

Comment: Maybe just add some boolean state and toggle it in the callback?

Comment: Do you mean that we don't useEffect and we can determine it through conditional statements?

Comment: No, you'll still use the `useEffect` to add/remove the listener. The state is to update and trigger React to rerender.

Comment: Please refer to the link mentioned below:

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: @DrewReese I think you can still update DOM, please check this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/change-body-background-color-0zlky?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @sid Hmm, you're right, it does seem to work in codesandbox at least. I even commented out the `alert` in case that was causing a browser rerender/repaint.

Comment: Jeje, can you provide more detail/context over what isn't working? Are there any errors? What browser/device are you running the code in? Is the above codesandbox working for you in the same environment as your code?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm touched by your help. But can I ask for your help a little help?
The layout should be covered in black, but only the alert appears. What should I do?

Comment: @DrewReese I am using next.js while testing at Chrome.
When you press the print screen, all ui disappears and only the black screen should appear.
Also, when the warning window is closed, all ui must appear again.

Comment: Codesandbox has a NextJS template. Could you try reproducing your code there and get it running then provide us a link to it? Kind of difficult to help debug otherwise IMO.

Comment: Thank you again for your help.
As I said, I will test it with a code sandbox and share the link. Thank you.

Comment: @Jeje can you join meeting and show your code & in browser? https://meet.google.com/vee-wmpv-qxq

Comment: @DrewReese When I checked in the sandbox, I checked that it worked. I confirmed that this cannot be done simply on my website. Maybe bg doesn't work because it's intertwined with other codes. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @sid Thank you for your help. However, it is difficult to accept the offer because there are codes that should not be exposed. Thank you so much for your kind behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try changing the keyup event to keydown to track the key press before it is triggered.

Also remember to unbind your event to avoid memory leaks.

```
useEffect(() => {
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (e.key === 'PrintScreen' || e.key === 'F13') {
        alert('test');
        document.body.style.zIndex = '999999';
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    }
})

return () => document.removeEventListener(‘keydown’)
```

}, [])

It should be something along these terms, didnt test it though.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The cord is working well!